# Uneven dataset regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Please suggest the regex for following dataset

```
gSoCa,['25','78'],fa,GT,GTM_19,gPfRec,['22','78','78'],10,fa,GT,TS/C_LE_RE,
gPreRe,['12'],10,fa,GT,TS/C_L_OW,gTLAsTe,['2'],PT,TEST/UP_P_IST,gBeAdRe,['78','2'],5,fa,GET,ulr/UTC_9,gEdiRen,['2'],fa,GT,ua/ngs_2018-Copy,
```

tried:

```
(\w+,(\['?\d+'?(?:,\s*'?\d+'?)*\]),(\w+),([\w/_-]+|[\w/]+),([\w/_-]+|[\w/]+)),
```

expected is python tuple:

```
[gSoCa,25,78,fa,GT,GTM_19,.....ua/ngs_2018-Copy]
```

see the demo
https://regex101.com/r/zHXUmh/1

Comment: You might consider splitting the file content by commas and then strip leading/trailing brackets and quotes.

Comment: I have removed your new question as it is unrelated to your original question. Your current question has valid answers (mine works; I didn't try the other).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could work:

```
text = """gSoCa,['25','78'],fa,GT,GTM_19,
gPfRec,['22','78','78'],10,fa,GT,TS/C_LE_RE,
gPreRe,['12'],10,fa,GT,TS/C_L_OW,
gTLAsTe,['2'],PT,TEST/UP_P_IST,
gBeAdRe,['78','2'],5,fa,GET,ulr/UTC_9,
gEdiRen,['2'],fa,GT,ua/ngs_2018-Copy,"""

result = [s.strip("[]'\n")  for s in  text.split(",")]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "expected" tuple is impossible in Python as it contains strings without quotes. That said, all it needs is a series of not-in-set characters:

```
print (tuple(re.findall(r"[^\[\],']+", text)))
```

result (as noted, *not* exactly what you want!):

```
('gSoCa', '25', '78', 'fa', 'GT', 'GTM_19', 'gPfRec', '22', '78', '78', '10', 'fa', 'GT', 'TS/C_LE_RE')
```